# Audio streaming with cookie - after log in (C# NAudio)

Tags: c#, naudio

I face issues with an online audio player using C# WPF. I can play online MP3 but if I have MP3 which requires login my NAudio library fails.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use cookies in NAudio library? I don't see this possibility.
2. Does anybody know about such library that can do this? I can't find any.
3. Any further suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kamil, without more detail it is impossible to answer the question unfortunately. Are you trying to use NAudio in a desktop application to play audio from a file hosted online? Or is NAudio being used in a web application itself? Please show the code that isn't working (if possible).

Comment: Hello
"Are you trying to use NAudio in a desktop application to play audio from a file hosted online" - Yes - WPF is desktop application

I can't show my code.

Comment: Hi @Kamil, already looked at that? [link](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using) , [link](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlayAudioFromUrl.md). There is the possibility to manage media access without the use of Naudio and only then pass this information on to the Naudio ...

Comment: Thanks. I must look on it - then more details